# Simple Android Layout Resize

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I'm attempting to resize buttons on rotate to expand proportionately.  Right now, they are a fix length, but I'm unsure of an alternative method to get the buttons to resize (setting the weight doesn't seem to help).  I want the buttons to essentially fill the length of the screen both vertically and horizontally.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainCommentBtn"
                android:layout_width="119dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/commentBtn" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainProfileBtn"
                android:layout_width="119dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/profileBtn" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainDetailBtn"
                android:layout_width="119dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/shareBtn" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your resource with this.  Copy the edited changes

Notice how there width is 0dp because they are using weight.
Using Weight:
1. In order to use weight you need to set the weightSum in the parent.
2. Make sure the width or height is set to 0 according to how you are using weight.
(for instance since we are going with horizontal orientation we want to use "0dp" width.  This allows weight to control the width of the object.
3. Lastly make sure the weight of all the objects add up to the weightSum.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainCommentBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/commentBtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainProfileBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/profileBtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainDetailBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/shareBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It'll be nice if you add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: ah, gotcha. sorry, my bad.

Comment: np I tried to draw it out a little more for him.  Weight can be confusing to understand to grasp at first

Comment: Unfortunately, that actually didn't do anything :(

Comment: Make sure you put that into a resource file I'll make the required changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an orientation for the `LinearLayout`.

I guess you want to use `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Then, in order to make `android:weight` work, you'd need to specify the width of every button as `0px` by using `android:layout_width="0px"` for every button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

These xml properties size the button to fill the screen both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layout with the help of layout weight so that it will automatically fill the screen in landscape mode also as below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```